# AspectJ AOP:after, when the method throws an excpetion

Tags: exception, aspectj

I've defined aspect over a certain method, that should be "activated" on method end:

```
    <aop:aspect id="HandlerClass" ref="handlerClass">
    <aop:after pointcut = "execution(* MyClass.myMethod(String, String, boolean))"
    method = "handlerMethod" ></aop:after>
```

The problem is that after MyClass.myMethod - The aspect does not work. 
While debugging, I've noticed that myMethod throws an exception.
Question is: Is this the expected behavior? I mean, should handlerClass.handlerMethod be called also when MyClass.myMethod throws an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AfterThrowing advice. See http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-advice.html for more info.